# CONVERT SQL VIEW INTO TABLE IN MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, wpf, view

I am using SQL server 2008. I have databases in SQL server which have tables and views in them. Currently, I am working in c# to develop a program which can pick a view from a table in SQL server and export in MYSQL as a table. So far I have made a form in C# which lets me selects a running SQL server then its available databases and then tables and views against a database selected.
For SQL part I am done but I don't have an idea on how to export that view from SQL  to MYSQL as a table. How can I give a connection string of MYSQL in c# so that it creates a table of view selected from MYSQL?. Here is my code so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> ServerNames = new List<String>();
        List<String> mysqlname = new List<String>();




        System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator servers = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        DataTable serversTable = servers.GetDataSources();

        foreach (DataRow row in serversTable.Rows)
        {
            string serverName = row[0].ToString();

            try
            {

                if (row[1].ToString() != "")
                {

                    serverName += "\\" + row[1].ToString();

                }


            }
            catch
            {


            }



            ServerNames.Add(serverName);
            serverscombo.Items.Add(serverName);


        }
    }

    private void serverscombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fromcombo = serverscombo.SelectedItem.ToString();
        servertxt.Text = fromcombo;

    }

    private void servertxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> databases = new List<String>();

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        connection.DataSource = servertxt.Text;
        // enter credentials if you want
        //connection.UserID = //get username;
        // connection.Password = //get password;
        connection.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        String strConn = connection.ToString();
        connglob = strConn;
        //create connection
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

        //open connection
        sqlConn.Open();

        //get databases
        DataTable tblDatabases = sqlConn.GetSchema("Databases");

        //close connection
        sqlConn.Close();

        //add to list
        foreach (DataRow row in tblDatabases.Rows)
        {
            String strDatabaseName = row["database_name"].ToString();

            databases.Add(strDatabaseName);

            databasenamescombo.Items.Add(strDatabaseName);
        }
    }

    private void databasenamescombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fromcombo2 = databasenamescombo.SelectedItem.ToString();

        //txtblob = fromcombo2;
        databasetxt.Text = fromcombo2;
        string val = databasetxt.Text;
        txtblob = val;


    }

    private void databasetxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> tble = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connglob))
        {
            con.Open();
            System.Text.StringBuilder myQuery = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            //myQuery.AppendFormat("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM {0}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'", databasetxt.Text);
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM [" + databasetxt.Text + "].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES",con))

            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add((string)reader["TABLE_NAME"]);
                    }
                }
            }

            colortxt.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
```

Comment: You want to copy data from SQL table to MYSQL table?

Comment: from sql view to mysql table

Comment: And mysql table is located on hosting where you have access to?

Comment: yes it is on my localhost

Comment: I am not expert in doing it but what i had like issue is that i couldn't connect directly to mysql database because of security on it (my mysql is on my web page). What i have done is create simple php RESTful API. If you do not know how it works you can look at [this](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html). It is not the simplest one but it works.